# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended- PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

I am trying to build a complex query, but I am not sure if I am structuring it right, as I am getting the error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. The error is happening at line 2. Please, could you help me with this. Thank you!

```
SELECT CNP,ValoareTotala 
FROM Vanzari AS V
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Functionar AS F
ON V.CNP= F.CNP
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Achizitii AS A
ON F.CNP= A.CNP
WHERE CNP in (SELECT CNP
FROM Achizitii
WHERE CNP =
(SELECT CNP
FROM Functionar
WHERE Nume='Alex Viseu'))
GROUP BY CNP, ValoareTotala
HAVING ValoareTotala>10
ORDER BY ValoareTotala DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `AS` for a table alias in Oracle. You can for column aliases, where it is optional, but it is not allowed for table aliases. You can see that [in the syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) - that shows `t_alias` without an optional `AS` keyword.

So remove that from all three references:

```
SELECT CNP,ValoareTotala 
FROM Vanzari V
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Functionar F
ON V.CNP= F.CNP
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Achizitii A
ON F.CNP= A.CNP
WHERE CNP in (SELECT CNP
FROM Achizitii
WHERE CNP =
(SELECT CNP
FROM Functionar
WHERE Nume='Alex Viseu'))
GROUP BY CNP, ValoareTotala
HAVING ValoareTotala>10
ORDER BY ValoareTotala DESC;
```

But you will also need to make it clear which table each column comes from, particularly where the same column name appears in more than one table - and as you have the join conditions `ON V.CNP= F.CNP` and `ON F.CNP= A.CNP` the column `CNP` exists in all three tables; so the other references to `CNP` will have to specify which one you mean.

It's also not really clear why you are using a subquery, particularly one that refers to the same tables again.

Comment: Thank you, @Alex Poole. Now I get it why I also receive "column ambiguously defined" error. The whole query is for learning purpose.

Comment: I see you were already told about the ambiguous column issue in [a comment on an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73504180/266304).